# How does python memory management work with variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management

Suppose i have a var like this.

```
num1 = 1
```

now If I do

```
num3 = num1
```

If I am correct this num3 is referencing to the value of num1 like pointer in C because when I do

```
print(num1 is num3)
```

It returns true because both are pointing at a same object or value in memory

But now if I change my value like this

```
num3 = 3
```

And then I print

```
print(num1,num3)
```

It returns "1,3"

Why hasn't the num1 value changed if I changed the second variable  value which is pointing to the same object or value

Comment: It is because integers are immutable.

Comment: @iz_ no **absolutely not**. The semantics here of assignment are the same regardless of the type of object. observer: `x = []; y = x; y = [1,2,3]; print(x, y)`

Comment: Because `num3 = 3` is merely saying "the name `num3` is now referring to the object `3`". That won't affect `num1`.

Comment: Note, pointers in C don't work this way either: https://repl.it/@juanpa_arrivillaga/TransparentUnfitDeskscan in any case, it is probably better to understand Python on it's own terms, it is a rather simple programming language. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oops, you're totally right :) I misread the question as changing the original variable to 3.

Comment: @iz_ not sure I understand, it still wouldn't work that way, and mutability is totally irrelevant to the semantics of assignment/name-binding.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, I'm clearly having a rough day, you're right again haha

Comment: you can run code on http://pythontutor.com/ to see how it use memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use mermaid to draw several sketches. Hope they are helpful to you:

### Int Assignment

[image: Int Assignment]

`A is B` is equivalent to `id(A) == id(B)`, the `id` of the variable that points to the same memory (rectangle in the sketch) is the same.

### List Assignment

**As mentioned in the comments, the assignment is the same regardless of the type.**

[image: List Assignment]

### What you should be careful

Objects which is referenced by multiple objects changing are what we need to worry about.

[image: What you should be careful]

Comment: You mean when I assign a new value the pointer that points to the memory is removed and instead the variable now points to a different chunk of memory!

Comment: Yes, but talking about pointers in Python doesn't seem to be Pythonic. I prefer to understand **Assignment** as referring to an object with a variable name. (Or stick a label on a box) If the variable already references another object, the old reference will be canceled. Objects not referenced by any variable will be recycled.

Comment: Yeah you mean they will be cleared by python with it's garbage collected right!